# How to add methods of class to a list inside the class with a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, class-members

I would like to update a "class-wide" list from a decorator that decorates the class' methods and adds each decorated method to that list.

This is what came to mind:

```py
def add(meth: callable):
    Spam.eggs.append(func)
    return meth

class Spam:
    eggs = []

    @add
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

This won't work though because `Spam` hasn't finished defining itself when `@add` is reached, and thus `add` raises a `NameError`, as pointed out in the comments.

I also tried a class method:

```py
class Spam:
    eggs = []

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, meth: callable):
        cls.eggs.append(meth)
        return meth

    @add
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

But this doesn't work either because when `@add` is reached, `add` is bound to the `classmethod` decorated instance, which is not callable.

---

Here is what I need this for:

I have a class with several methods that take one argument (besides `self`) that transform that object in such a way that these methods may be composed with one another. I want to decorate each of these in such a way that they're automatically added to a list in the class.

E.g.:

```py
from typing import List

def transform_meth(meth: callable):
    TextProcessor.transforms.add(meth)
    return meth

class TextProcessor:
    transforms: List[callable] = []

    @transform_meth
    def m1(self, text):
        return text

    @transform_meth
    def m2(self, text):
        return text

    def transform(self, text):
        for transform in self.transforms:
            text = transform(text)
        return text
```

I could add the methods in the list manually, but I find the decorator to be clearer since it is close to the definition of the method, and thus it is easier to remember to decorate a new method when defining it than adding it to the list manually.

Comment: If your decorator is so tightly bound to the current definition of `Spam`, why use a decorator in the first place? At the very least, it still has to return `func`.

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this instead of a using a property and set/get?

Comment: Can you check your code, it gives me `NameError: name 'Spam' is not defined` when I run it

Comment: Related to @DeveshKumarSingh's comment, the only way your code runs without that error is if `Spam` was already defined and you are re-defining it, in which case `foo` is updating the *original* class when it gets called, and that class gets replaced once the `class` statement is finished being evaluated.

Comment: @chepner That was the problem. With the code as is, when the decorator gets called, `Spam` doesn't exist yet because the definition hasn't finished?

Comment: Correct. This gets tricky, because a class doesn't produce a proper scope; otherwise, you could simply define your decorator *inside* the class and let the decorator declare `transforms` as nonlocal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach fails because when `transform_meth` is called, `TextProcessor` isn't bound to anything yet (or if it is, that object gets overwritten when the `class` statement completes).

The simple solution would be to define `transform_meth` inside the `class` statement, so that it could simply declare `transforms` as a nonlocal variable. However, that won't work because a `class` statement doesn't establish a new scope.

Instead, you can define a function that *creates* the decorator, which takes the desired list (at that point a just a name in the body of the `class` statement, not from any assumed scope). That function returns a closure over the list argument
so that you can append to it.

```
def make_decorator(lst):

    # *This* will be the function bound to the name 'transform_meth'
    def _(meth):
        lst.append(meth)
        return meth

    return _


class TextProcessor:
    transforms: List[callable] = []

    transform_meth = make_decorator(transforms)

    @transform_meth
    def m1(self, text):
        return text

    @transform_meth
    def m2(self, text):
        return text

    def transform(self, text):
        for transform in self.transforms:
            text = transform(text)
        return text

    del transform_meth  # Not needed anymore, don't create a class attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the arg of each method is self you can append to the object instance like so:

```
from functools import wraps

def appender(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        if f not in args[0].transforms:
            args[0].transforms.append(f)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return func

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.transforms = []
    @appender
    def m1(self, arg1):
        return arg1
    @appender
    def m2(self, arg1):
        return arg1
    def transform(self, text):
        methods = [f for f in dir(self) if not f.startswith("__") and callable(getattr(self,f)) and f != 'transform']
        for f in methods:
            text = getattr(self,f)(text)
        return text

f = Foo()
f.transform('your text here')
print(f.transforms)
```

Output:

```
[<function Foo.m1 at 0x1171e4e18>, <function Foo.m2 at 0x1171e4268>]
```

Comment: The problem here is that the method gets added to the list each time it's called (e.g. by calling `f.m1('a')` again, `m1` gets re-added to the list). It should only be added once, at the time the decorator is called.

Comment: ^ editted to account for this. You could also use a set instead of a list if you don't care about the order.

Comment: Still, the problem remains. The methods should be added by order of definition, and independently of whether they're ever called directly. Consider the `transform` method above. If we skip the `m1` and `m2` calls, and call `f.transform('some text')`, neither `m1` nor `m2` will be called, since `f.transforms` will be empty (because the methods haven't been called yet). Instead, we would like both `m1` and `m2` to be in the list (and in that order) as soon as the class is defined.

Comment: how's that? You could move the `transform` call into the `__init__` if you want it to be done at instantiation